# How to create a function that encodes run-length using fold_right?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml, higher-order-functions

I created a function and helper function that find the number of repeating elements in a list, and what those elements.

```
let rec _encode l x =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | head::rest -> (if head = x then 1 else 0) + encode rest x

let encode l x = ((_encode l x), x)
```

In this case, I have to specify what that element is for it to search.

So this is a two part question. 1) How do I do it to return a list of tuples, with format `(int * 'a) list`, where `int` is the # of rep, and `'a` is the element that is repeating.

2) How would I implement this using fold_right?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
let encode (l : 'a list) : (int * 'a) list = fold_right (fun (x,hd) lst -> 
    match x with 
    | [] -> 0
    | hd :: rest -> if hd x then (x+1, hd) else (x, hd)) l []
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt looks very confused:

- It doesn't use `lst`, `hd` (the first one), or `rest`.
- `x` is used as a list (`match x with []`) and a number (`x+1`).
- The elements of `x` (list) are functions that return bools?? (`... hd::rest -> ... if hd x`)
- The function sometimes returns a number (`0`) and sometimes a tuple (`(x, hd)`).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
let encode l =
    let f x = function
              | (n, y) :: zs when x = y -> (n + 1, y) :: zs
              | zs                      -> (1, x) :: zs
    in
    fold_right f l []
```

Which is the same as:

```
let encode l =
    let f x z = match z with
                | (n, y) :: zs when x = y -> (n + 1, y) :: zs
                | zs                      -> (1, x) :: zs
    in
    fold_right f l []
```

Which is the same as:

```
let encode l =
    fold_right (fun x z ->
        match z with
        | (n, y) :: zs when x = y -> (n + 1, y) :: zs
        | zs                      -> (1, x) :: zs
    ) l []
```

Comment: Could you explain? I don't really follow, and I really want to understand what's happening. Could this be written let encode l = fold_right (fun x ----  I get lost here because I thought that the function in fold_right takes two args, one being hd and the other being the accumulated list

Comment: @Test I've expanded the answer a bit more.